# Upgrade from xls workbook to xlsx, file extension not appended in response

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have updated a method to download the file from the server from XLS to XLSX. I am using apache poi library to generate the excel workbook and then using streaming output entity to send the response back to the client.

Earlier when i was using XLS methods the final response used to look like:

```
return Response.ok(entity)
    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=abc.xls")
    .type("application/vnd.ms-excel")
    .build();
```

I was getting response as Response.xls, but now when i am using poi-ooxml library with following code, i am getting response without file extension:

```
return Response.ok(entity)
    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=abc.xlsx")
    .type("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
    .build();
```

Note: I am calling this API from the postman, is the MIME type for xlxs is not correct? File content and everything is correct only the issue is file extension is not appended to file name.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check the http request also.
If possible please provide us the exact request along with valid payload.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with Postman, postman doesn't work in a way like how browsers work. When same API was called using browser it worked awesomely with no issue. In-spite of using postman for such kind of file download testing better use **RESTLET CLIENT**. Restlet Client works like a charm for this scenario.